# How can I prove that this edge traversing algorithm works?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, matrix, geometry, computational-geometry

I've come across an algorithm, which finds the contour of a figure, but I have trouble proving why it works, I have *sort of* understood why it works, but I can't derive the formulas used in there myself.

This is the algorithm:

Let's assume that we have a binary image (with the figure being black and background being white). All the pixels are stored in a binary matrix with 1 being white and 0 being black.

0) Find the first black pixel (for example if it's a square then it's located in the top left corner).

1) Set Lx = x and Ly = y (coordinates of that first pixel), and Rx = x - 1 and Ry = y. Also keep 2 constants firstX = x and firstY = y (we'll need them later).

2) Calculate Tx = Rx + Ly - Ry and Ty = Ry + Rx - Lx.

3) Do the following loop:

```
do {
        if (m[Tx][Ty] == 0) {
            Lx = Tx;
            Ly = Ty;
            m2[Tx][Ty] = 0;
        } else {
            Rx = Tx;
            Ry = Ty;
        }
        if (Lx == Rx || Ly == Ry) {
            Tx = Rx + Ly - Ry;
            Ty = Ry + Rx - Lx;
        } else {
            Ty = (Ly + Ry - Lx + Rx) / 2;
            Tx = (Lx + Rx + Ly - Ry) / 2;
        }
    } while (Tx != firstX || Ty != firstY);
```

In the code above **m** is the original image and **m2** is the image containing only the contour.

I have tried to visualize how this works and this is what i got:

[image]

So apparently it's doing some sort of zigzag movements to get those zeros on edges and determine the contour.

So, my question is, is this a known algorithm? And how exactly were these formulas derived:

```
Tx = Rx + Ly - Ry;
Ty = Ry + Rx - Lx;
```

and

```
Ty = (Ly + Ry - Lx + Rx) / 2;
Tx = (Lx + Rx + Ly - Ry) / 2;
```

?

Comment: Intersting, I have never seen that. Can we havevthe reference ? It could be similar to the "right hand on the wall" strategy to traverse a maze.  The classical methods are described here: http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/index.html.

Comment: I haven't looked closely yet, but the Tx/Ty formulas are certainly based on the fact that the points L and R are in a close neighborhood of T, and are used to compute another point in the neighborhood, such as finding the next clockwise neighbor or similar.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Unfortunately, I don't have any reference, I was sent this algorithm by someone who got it from someone else, who got it from someone else, etc, but I'll ask if they have any derivations! Thank you very much for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:

Throughout execution, R, L and T are immediate 8-neighbors (in the [Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood) sense).

The algorithm repeatedly assigns T to one of R and L, depending on the value at T, so that L is always on a black pixel and R on a white one. Then it recomputes T by rotating RL around R.

---

Assume for a while that `Rx=Ry=0`; then if L is a 4-neighbor, `(Tx,Ty):=(Ly,-Lx)`, a rotation by 90°; else, `(Tx,Ty):=((Lx+Ly)/2,((Ly-Lx)/2)`, a rotation by 45°. This rule is illustrated below:

[image]

---

The initial configuration is the top-left in the figure, with L being the first black pixel. Given the progression rule, it is obvious that the algorithm will follow a chain (sequence of 8-connected pixels).

In fact, for a position of R, one rotates L around it, until a black pixel is found; then one moves R to that pixel. This is the very procedure named [Radial Sweep](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/ray.html).

We can rewrite it in the equivalent form (after renaming `R=B`, `L=W`, and defining `Rot` to be the rotation rule above.)

```
B, W= B0, LeftOf(B0)
do
    while Rot(B, W) is White
        W= Rot(B, W)
    B= Rot(B, W)
while B != B0
```

Remains to prove that

1. the chain is closed (we will come back to the starting pixel),
2. it is the contour of a blob (every pixel in the chain has both black and white neighbors),
3. no pixels are missed.

More precisely, L follows the inner contour, while R follows the outer one (and T doing both).

Comment: if you want to finish proving things, you should look up "polygon law of vector addition" (a.k.a. "polygon law of forces" in physics). But yeah, I also realized that those are just vector operations!

Comment: A proof requires good understanding of some of the topics of digital geometry such as in "Digital Topology, Azriel Rosenfeld, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 86, No. 8. (Oct., 1979), pp. 621-630." (Sections 2., 3., 5.)